# Log into external web app using NetSuite Credentials - Singe Sign on | SuiteSignOn

Tags: netsuite, suitecommerce

For our usecase/situation below; should we be using SuiteSignOn to make an outbound call or an inbound call?

**Usecase:**
We have a Netsuite webstore (SCA). People login and purchase medical tests from us. After customers have performed their medical test they can view their results in our external web application (PHP Laravel web app). We want to use 1 single sign on for both applications (NS webstore and Results web app). Ie, the user will use their SCA webstore account login details to login to both applications.

**We expect customers to go to the Results web app and somehow login using their NetSuite user credentials.** I assume NetSuite (SuiteSignOn) can embed a login form in a external web app?

So would the above usecase be considered a SuiteSignOn outbound call or SuiteSignOn inbound call?

Answer (score 0):

Check into Google Auth.  That is supposed to be released as soon as all of the 2017.1 upgrades are rolled out.  That would allow you to use the same authentication credentials.